# Is it possible to change values in edge://prefs-internals?

Tags: preferences

I have need of changing a setting in `edge://prefs-internals`

Specifically, I want to add and entry next to `extensions_to_open` within the `download` node so that a downloaded file always opens with its associated application.  Currently, when I type `edge://prefs-internals` in as an edge url. the data (I have read it's in JSON, but do not know) for prefs-internals is displayed.  Is there a way that I can modify the blank entry to include my file extension so that the file, when downloaded in edge, will open?

I have opened the internals page by putting `edge://prefs-internals` in as the url and pressing enter but the data are not editable in the resulting display.